# WebGL/THREE.js Reading floating point textures

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl

I was trying to figure out how to read the data from a floating point texture using three.js and I came across this post: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9513

I am able to successfully read from the floating point textures on firefox, however in chrome it throws the same error:

> `THREE.WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels`: renderTarget is not in UnsignedByteType or implementation defined type.

I am not sure what I need to do to be able to read the textures, any help would be greatly appreciated.